# source_sink `library(matrix)' does not exist

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am attempting to use the [matrix module](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/matrix/prolog/matrix.pl) in SWI-Prolog, however, upon trying to use the module I get the following error:

```
source_sink `library(matrix)' does not exist
```

The line I use to import, at the top of my .pl file, is:

```
:- use_module(library(matrix)).
```

When I try downloading the file, using `pack_install(matrix).`, it returns the following error:

```
ERROR: source_sink `path(git)' does not exist
```

I'm not sure if this might have any influence, but I also import another library in the exact same way in the line above (that one works). I am not super familiar with Prolog/Swirl yet, what might cause these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to use the ["matrix" pack](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=matrix).

You need to install it first; start `swipl` and then enter this command (for more details, see [pack_install/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=pack_install/2)):

```
pack_install(matrix).
```

Comment: When I try the installer, I get: ```ERROR: source_sink `path(git)' does not exist```

Comment: Seems like does recognize the command and knows which package it has to install, but then something goes wrong (detailed screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/e906e2ffb79a7397a6350687e994a549.png)

Comment: Sorry; can't help you. It works fine for me on Linux.

Comment: You might try asking for help at https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/

Answer (score 0):

Swi-Prolog `pack_install` needs `git` internally to install packages. Please ensure the git is installed in your system.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."